# Laravel Search Functionality with 'When' Function

Tags: laravel, search

I have implemented the search functionality in Laravel with the help of "When"  function and it is working fine but I am wondering about which logic it is implementing at the backend, I mean is it implementing the "OR" or "AND" . For me, it is working on "OR" logic but kindly correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

for me it is working on "OR" logic as we can take some of the value like: we just took min price or max price and the rest of the attribute's can be left and still it is working